# get the MvcHtmlString for an Action in custom Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a custom html helper that will display a dynamic content based on the Action passed to this html helper, here what I have so far

```
// the Area helper class
public static class AreaHelper
{
      public static AreaBuilder CustomArea(this HtmlHelper helper)
      {
           return new AreaBuilder();
      }
}
// the area builder class
public class AreaBuilder: IHtmlString
{
    private string name;
    private string caption;
    private string action;
    private string controller;
    private object routeData;

    public AreaBuilder Name(string name)
    {
        this.name=name;
        return this;
    }

    public AreaBuilder Action(string action,string controller,object routeData)
    {
        this.action=action;
        this.controller=controller;
        this.routeData=routeData;
        return this;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
         var html=new StringBuilder();
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div id=""{0}"" class=""area"">",name);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-caption"">{0}</div>",caption);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-content"">{0}</div>",**what should i do here**);
         html.Append("</div>");
         return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am not able to do the proper steps in order to get the content of the ActionResult that its url I have it ( action , controller,routeData)

in other words, how can I get the Action as mvchtmlstring?

any help is appreciated

Comment: Just so you are aware, there is a TagBuilder class you can use to construct HTML fragments. Here's an article showing how: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

**Solution I**

1. `Add reference to System.Web.Mvc.Html`;
2. `ChildActionExtensions.Action(YourHtmlHelper, action,controller,routeData)`;

so your code will become like

```
// the area builder class
public class AreaBuilder: IHtmlString
{
    private string name;
    private string caption;
    private string action;
    private string controller;
    private object routeData;
    private HtmlHelper htmlHelper;

    public AreaBuilder Name(string name)
    {
        this.name=name;
        return this;
    }

    public AreaBuilder HtmlHelper(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        this.htmlHelper=helper;
        return this;
    }

    public AreaBuilder Action(string action,string controller,object routeData)
    {
        this.action=action;
        this.controller=controller;
        this.routeData=routeData;
        return this;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
         var html=new StringBuilder();
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div id=""{0}"" class=""area"">",name);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-caption"">{0}</div>",name);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-content"">{0}</div>",ChildActionExtensions.Action(htmlHelper, action,controller,routeData));
         html.Append("</div>");
         return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

and your Area Html Helper

```
// the Area helper class
public static class AreaHelper
{
      public static AreaBuilder CustomArea(this HtmlHelper helper)
      {
           return new AreaBuilder().HtmlHelper(helper);
      }
}
```

**Solution II**

There is another way to achieve what you are looking for, you can make something like the following

```
// the area builder class
public class AreaBuilder: IHtmlString
{
    private string name;
    private string caption;
    private MvcHtmlString content; // to allow the use to add html content

    public AreaBuilder Name(string name)
    {
        this.name=name;
        return this;
    }

    public AreaBuilder Content(Func<object, HelperResult> html)
    {
        var detail=html.Invoke(null);
        this.content=MvcHtmlString.Create(detail.ToHtmlString());
        return this;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
         var html=new StringBuilder();
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div id=""{0}"" class=""area"">",name);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-caption"">{0}</div>",caption);
         html.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""area-content"">{0}</div>",content.ToHtmlString());
         html.Append("</div>");
         return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

and in your code you do the following even though the name should be CustomArea in my opinion and not CustomButton.

```
@Html.CustomArea().Name("MyArea").Content(@<text>@Html.Action("YourAction","YourController",...your routing data)</text>)
```

hope this will help you

Comment: thank you, I tried both solutions and they worked as I wished

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you might be better off building an extension method on HtmlHelper, like so:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AreaButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string areaName, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeData = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.AddCssClass("area");
    div.GenerateId(areaName);

    var caption = new TagBuilder("div");
    caption.AddCssClass("area-caption");
    caption.InnerHtml = areaName;

    div.InnerHtml = caption.ToString();

    var content = new TagBuilder("div");
    content.AddCssClass("area-content");
    content.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeData, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();

    div.InnerHtml += content.ToString();

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(div.ToString());
}
```

This method would need to be defined in a static class, which I've omitted. Extending the HtmlHelper allows you to take advantage of the tools that are already in the framework, like the TagBuilder, and to leverage everything already available in the helper class (like the ViewContext). To use, do something like:

```
@Html.AreaButton("admin", "Administration", "index", "home", new { area="admin" }, new { /* attributes to add the link itself */ })
```

If you're trying to build a link to an area, you need to add the "area" value into the route dictionary you pass into the ActionLink helper method, like I've shown above.

Comment: thank you, what I missed was htmlHelper.ActionLink or as what @HadiHassan also mentioned in his first solution, I don't have enough point to vote your answer up